# Call javascript function in return statement

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Hi I have a Javascript function which returns the following as string

```
    return "<b>" + param1 + "</b><br /><a target='_blank' href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + param2  +">Wikipedia Entry</a>";
```

The string returned is presented as a link.

I would like to call a separate function when clicking on the link. i.e. I would like to build return string as below.

```
return "<b></b><a target='_blank' href="#" onClick=\"MyFunction('" + param1    +"', '" +param2+"')\">Wikipedia Entry</a>";
```

Any idea what's the issue with above?

Comment: You have to escape the quotation marks at `href="#"`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Since `onClick` is an attribute, you should wrap it's value in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As `param1` and `param2` are variables which you are using when creating string, you need to concatenate its value and its important to wrap it in quotes.

```
return "<b></b><a href=\"#\" onClick=\"MyFunction('" + param1 +"', '" +param2+"')\">Wikipedia Entry</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks. This works i.e. does not error. However the string 'Wikipedia Entry' does not appear as a link anymore.

Comment: hmm not sure why it's not calling MyFunction() onclick. I have just added an alert in myFunction. and even removed all parameters as   return "<b></b><a href=\"#\" onClick=\"MyFunction()\">Wikipedia Entry</a>"; See sandbox example at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_extendInfowindow

Answer (score 0):

:)

```js
function fn01(){
  var param1 = "param1"; 
  var param2 = 1000;  
  
  param1 = ' " ' + param1 + ' " ';   //<---- add " in param1
  param2 = ' " ' + param2 + ' " ';   //<---- add " in param2
  
  var body = document.getElementById('link')
  var b = "<b></b><a target='_blank' href='#' onClick='MyFunction("+ param1 +", " + param2 +")'>Wikipedia Entry</a>";  // <--- remove ' out MyFunction
  
  body.innerHTML += b + "<br/><br/><br/>";
}

function MyFunction(str1,str2){
  console.log(str1);
  console.log(str2);
}
```

```css
a {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
<a onClick="fn01()" > get a tag</a>
<br/><br/>
<div id="link">

</div>
```